# Want to do Call Forward functionality in android

Tags: android

I am new user here. I want to make call forwarding functionality in my app and.
Suppose I call to X number then it forward to Y number automatically. Here I write my code that I tested. But its not working. Please help me.. I need it by tonight end... Please

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  
{
private Context mContext;
private boolean isRinging = false;
private boolean callReceived = false;

TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
public static CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener;
private String default_number = "x";
private String callForwardNumber = "y";   

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    customPhoneListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener();
    telephonyManager.listen(customPhoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE 
            | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_FORWARDING_INDICATOR
            | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);
    mContext = context;

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) 
    {
        if (getResultData()!=null && getResultData().equalsIgnoreCase(default_number)) 
        {
              String url = "tel:"+"**21*"+ callForwardNumber+Uri.encode("#");
              Intent intent1 = (new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url)));
              intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              mContext.startActivity(intent1);

//              setResultData(callForwardNumber);
        }
    }
}

private class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener 
{
    @Override
    public void onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged(boolean cfi) {
      Log.e("","onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged  CFI ="+cfi);
        super.onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged(cfi);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
    {
        switch (state) 
        {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
//              Toast.makeText(mContext, "It was a ringing call from "+incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isRinging = true;
            break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
//              Toast.makeText(mContext, "It was a offhook call from "+incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            callReceived = true;
            break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            if(isRinging == true && callReceived == false)
            {
//                  Toast.makeText(mContext, "It was a missed call from "+incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //                  Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AddActivity.class);
                //                  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                //                  mContext.startActivity(intent);
                telephonyManager.listen(null, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
            }
            else if(isRinging == true && callReceived == true)
            {
//                  Toast.makeText(mContext, "Call Received.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(isRinging == false && callReceived == true)
            {
//                  Toast.makeText(mContext, "Call Ended.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //                  Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AddActivity.class);
                //                  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                //                  mContext.startActivity(intent);
                telephonyManager.listen(null, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
            }


            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```